# Minify Arrays with chrome set

Tags: jquery, arrays, set, minify

My following code works. However is there anyway to condense/minify it?

```
chrome.storage.local.get({wsitemnumberget: [], wstitleget: [], wspecialpriceget: [], wspecialprevpriceget: [], wspecialdeldateget: []}, function (result) {
var wsitemnumberget = result.wsitemnumberget;
var wstitleget = result.wstitleget;
var wspecialpriceget = result.wspecialpriceget;
var wspecialprevpriceget = result.wspecialprevpriceget;
var wspecialdeldateget = result.wspecialdeldateget;

var witenumfetch = $('#wsitemnumber').text();
var wspecialtitlefetch = $('#title').val();
var wspecialprice = $('.mwsb-wsp').text();
var wspecialprevprice = $('.mwsb-prevprice').text();
var wspecialdeldate = $('.mwsb-deldate').text();

wsitemnumberget.push({WSItemNumber: witenumfetch});
wstitleget.push({WSTitle: wspecialtitlefetch});
wspecialpriceget.push({WSPrice: wspecialprice});
wspecialprevpriceget.push({WSPrevPrice: wspecialprevprice});
wspecialdeldateget.push({WSDELDate: wspecialdeldate});
chrome.storage.local.set({ wsitemnumberget: wsitemnumberget, wstitleget: wstitleget, wspecialpriceget: wspecialpriceget, wspecialprevpriceget: wspecialprevpriceget, wspecialdeldateget: wspecialdeldateget });`
```

Currently the above code puts all the sections into arrays with names using push.
However is there a way to keep my names with the data and minify the code and output using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to minify this and it still works.

**Possible to go even smaller than this?**

```
chrome.storage.local.get({wsitemadded: []}, function (result) {
var wsitemadded = result.wsitemadded;

var witenumfetch = $('#wsitemnumber, .mwsb-wsp, .mwsb-prevprice, .mwsb-deldate').text();
var wspecialtitlefetch = $('#title').val();
var wspecialprice = $('.mwsb-wsp').text();
var wspecialprevprice = $('.mwsb-prevprice').text();
var wspecialdeldate = $('.mwsb-deldate').text();
var wspecialimg = $('#postad-img-0 div img').attr('src'); 

wsitemadded.push({WSItemNumber: witenumfetch, WSTitle: wspecialtitlefetch, WSImage: wspecialimg, WSPrice: wspecialprice, WSPrevPrice: wspecialprevprice, WSDELDate: wspecialdeldate});
chrome.storage.local.set({ wsitemadded: wsitemadded });
});`
```